# .tr0 file format

Tags: simulation, spice

I am trying to find out some information regarding ".tr0" file format which is produced in the output of [HSPICE simulation](http://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece482/tutorials/spice.html). I find some relative information about the .tr0 file but nothing about its format.Below is the information.

*.tr0 : Binary file containing transient analysis waveforms.

If anybody can explain the file format of .tr0 file, it will be of great help.

Comment: If you don't have any luck getting an answer in the next day or so you could also try including a hex dump of a reasonable portion of the file created by following that tutorial. It might be a sufficiently simple format for someone to be able to reverse-engineer it.

Answer (score 1):

**SPICE Transient Analysis output file**

*The tr0 file extension its a binary file and is associated with SPICE (Simulation Program with Integrated Circuit Emphasis). The tr0 files are used for Transient Analysis Output.*

More info [here](http://whatis.techtarget.com/fileformat/TR0-SPICE-Transient-Analysis-output-file) and [here](http://www.file-extensions.org/tr0-file-extension).

SPICE Commercial Version Softwares:

- PSpice/OrCAD
- SPICE OPUS
- HSpice (UNIX)
- HSIM
- MicroCad
- Dr. Spice
- T-Spice
- Intusoft
- Spice-It!
- SIMetrix (Windows and Linux)
- TopSPICE
- NG-spice
- MultiSIM
- SmartSpice
- TINA
- Spectre
- Eldo
- UltraSim
- MacSpice
- NanoSim
- NSPICE
- B2SPICE
- ICAP/4
- TINA-TI
- Proteus ISIS (Labcenter Electronics)
- LTSpice IV (Linear Technology)

Comment: This software would certainly display the waveform using tr0, but i was rather interested in getting the format of tr0 file which anyhow, i cant get .Anyhow i tried using that software using CMD in windows.I don't have much experience in windows CMD, but anyhow, it didn't run.They hadn't provided any .exe file for running the program..

Comment: @shailendra I added some softwares examples.

Comment: Thanks butzke, will certainly use one of them to see the waveform generated by the tr0 file

Comment: @shailendra if the answer had helped can you vote or put as ansered the question?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get much of the information, but after some research over Google i find this information.

The tr0 file is a binary file which is produced by HSPICE or SPICE .
 .tr0 contain the simulation waveforms information which generally include name of the variable , a particular time stamp and value of the variable at a particular time stamp.

You can get more information on "tr0" file [at his link](http://www.freelists.org/post/si-list/tr0-file-viewer)

Comment: This link don't say anything about the file format

Comment: @Butzke: This is all i can get after a lot of search..nothing else..

Comment: I added the sources that I got my answer.

Answer (score 0):

it depends upon option given in vector file

for POST=1 o/p is binary file

for POST=2 o/p is ASCII format

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! From the question it's pretty clear that the OP is interested in the binary file format, and not the ASCII file format. So, your answer is not really an answer at all. Please be careful to answer the question as it is asked.